# GNUplot nothing is plotting

Tags: c, plot, pipe, gnuplot, heatmap

I'm trying to represent the diffusion of temperature on an aluminum plate over time.

I'm using GNUplot to show the result on the form of a heatmap. The problem is that, I would like for the graph to evolve over time and show me the evolution of the heatmap overtime.

```
double T0 = 20;
double D = 9.7 / (10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10);
double h = 0.001;

double *U = malloc(ia[n] * sizeof(double));
double *result = malloc(n * sizeof(double));

for(int i = 0; i < ia[n]; i++){
  U[i] = T0;
}



FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
fprintf(fp, "unset key\n");
fprintf(fp, "set view map\n");
fprintf(fp, "set pm3d interpolate 10,10\n");

for (double k = 0.0; k < 10; k = k + 0.01) {
  fprintf(fp, "splot '-' with pm3d\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result[i] = 0.0;
    for (int j = ia[i]; j < ia[i + 1]; j++) {
      result[i] += (-D) * U[j] * a[j]; 
    }
    U[i] = U[i] + (h * result[i]);
    fprintf(fp, "%f %f %f\n", datax[i], datay[i], U[i]);
  }
  fprintf(fp, "\n\n");
  fprintf(fp, "e\n");
  fflush(fp);
}
fclose(fp);
```

This code is based on another code that I wrote that simulates the oscillation of the same aluminum plate.

When launched, the GNUplot window open and only show me the axes and the corresponding between the colours and the temperature. The only thing that changes overtime is  the corresponding between the colours and the temperature where new colours appears for colder temperature, which is expected.

My terminal doesn't give me any error or what so ever.

If someone could find a solution to my problem it would be very helpful.

Comment: What I'd recommend to debug this is to replace the `popen` with `fopen` and write all the data to a file. Then, you can inspect the data with a text editor. You can then manually run the file through `gnuplot`. You could manually edit the plot file, tweaking, until you figure out what is missing. Then, modify your program. Lather, rinse, repeat ... Then, when you have the final working version, you can go back to using `popen` _Side note:_ If you do `popen`, you should do `pclose` instead of `fclose`

Comment: Your code is incomplete. (e.g.) `ia`, `datax`, `datay`, ... are _not_ defined. We want an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we would like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].

Comment: Thank you i will try to debug it by using your method.